# Join in laravel with case and when statement

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I've following query in Mysql :

```
SELECT 
U.* FROM
`cr_friends` AS `cf`  JOIN
`users` AS `U` WHERE
    `cf`.`status` = 1
    AND 
    (
        CASE
            WHEN `cf`.`friend_to` = 1 THEN `cf`.`friend_from` = `U`.`id`
            WHEN `cf`.`friend_from` = 1 THEN `cf`.`friend_to` = `U`.`id`
        END
    ) GROUP BY `U`.`id` ORDER BY `cf`.`created` desc;
```

I'm trying to put this in laravel in following way :

```
$myFriendsData = DB::table('cr_friends as cf')
        ->where('cf.status', '=', 1)
        ->Join('users as U')
        ->select(
            DB::raw(
                '(
                    CASE WHEN cf.friend_to = ' . auth()->user()->id . ' THEN cf.friend_from = U.id  END
                    CASE WHEN cf.friend_from = ' . auth()->user()->id . ' THEN cf.friend_to = U.id  END
                )'
            )
        )
        ->select('U.*')
        ->orderBy('U.id', 'desc')
        ->get();
```

but didnt succeed as the mysql query is perfectly working fine but this laravel query wont.

Actually What I think is, there is problem with the Join which I'm putting in laravel it asking for one more parameter but in this case I'm unable to do that.

Can you guys please guide me so that I can achieve this.

Thanks
Randheer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provide an empty closure for `join()` and use `whereRaw()`:

```php
$myFriendsData = DB::table('cr_friends as cf')
    ->where('cf.status', '=', 1)
    ->join('users as U', function() {})
    ->whereRaw(
        '(
            CASE 
                 WHEN cf.friend_to = ' . auth()->user()->id . ' THEN cf.friend_from = U.id
                 WHEN cf.friend_from = ' . auth()->user()->id . ' THEN cf.friend_to = U.id  
            END
        )'
    )
    ->select('U.*')
    ->orderBy('U.id', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks @Jonas it worked there is a minor change in case statement which is in case statement we have have to use that in following manner that's it  :

CASE WHEN cf.friend_to = ' . auth()->user()->id . ' THEN cf.friend_from = U.id 
            WHEN cf.friend_from = ' . auth()->user()->id . ' THEN cf.friend_to = U.id  END

Answer (score 1):

I used the `DB::raw` for `case end` statement in `join` in Laravel Version 5.8

```
DB::table('users')
    ->join('settings', function ($join) {
        $join->on('settings.id', '=', DB::raw(case when users.type = "admin" then users.admin_setting_id else users.setting_id end'));
    })
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
$myFriendsData = DB::table('cr_friends as cf')
    ->Join('users as U')
    ->where('cf.status', '=', 1)
    ->where(
        DB::raw(
            '(
                CASE WHEN cf.friend_to = ' . auth()->user()->id . ' THEN cf.friend_from = U.id  END
                CASE WHEN cf.friend_from = ' . auth()->user()->id . ' THEN cf.friend_to = U.id  END
            )'
        )
    )
    ->select('U.*')
    ->orderBy('U.id', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

Comment: @Shaiendra thanks for your response, I tried the above but it didn't worked it's giving me 

"Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::join(), 1 passed "

Comment: I think in Join it didn't take one argument it requires minimum 2 argument should be passed.